# Get the hex color code for each value of a column based on a cmap

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df_slope` with `Year` and `Slope` columns:

```
    Year    Slope
0   1970    0.283962
1   1971    0.146310
2   1972    -0.548499
3   1973    0.680444
4   1974    0.801810
5   1975    0.354132
... ...     ...
51  2021    0.180423
52  2022    0.597477
53  2023    0.097228
```

I would like to assign a hex color code to each Year from its Slope value based on a matplotlib cmap, e.g. "jet".

```
norm = plt.Normalize(df_slope['Slope'].min() - df_slope['Slope'].max())
cmap = 'jet'  # 'Reds'
```

[image]

What I wanted to achieve is to assign a color to a Year, where a color should be a value somewhere between the min (dark blue = min of Slope) and max (dark red = max of Slope) of the color map of "jet" based on the Slope value accordingly.

```
    Year    Slope        color_hex
0   1970    0.283962     ?
1   1971    0.146310     ?
2   1972    -0.548499    ?
3   1973    0.680444     ?
4   1974    0.801810     ?
5   1975    0.354132     ?
... ...     ...
51  2021    0.180423     ?
52  2022    0.597477     ?
53  2023    0.097228     ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package cmasher to translate a float in a color map to a hex color.

```
import cmasher as cmr

df = pd.DataFrame({'norm' : [0.1,0.6,0.9,0.4]})
df.norm.apply(lambda x: cmr.take_cmap_colors('jet', 1, cmap_range=(x, x),
                     return_fmt='hex'))


0    [#0000F1]
1    [#CEFF29]
2    [#F10800]
3    [#29FFCE]
Name: norm, dtype: object
```

The function `take_cmap_colors` can give multiple color values in a certain range, but in this example we only ask for one value in a range that is infinetely small, which is exactly the color at the specific position that we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex

c = plt.get_cmap(cmap)

df['color'] = pd.Series(norm(df_slope['Slope']), index=df.index
                        ).map(lambda x: to_hex(c(x)))
```

Output:

```
    Year     Slope    color
0   1970  0.283962  #ff8d00
1   1971  0.146310  #ffc800
2   1972 -0.548499  #13fce4
3   1973  0.680444  #bf0000
4   1974  0.801810  #800000
5   1975  0.354132  #ff6f00
51  2021  0.180423  #ffb900
52  2022  0.597477  #ed0400
53  2023  0.097228  #ffde00
```